# How to enable client-side logging of Websphere MQ?

Tags: java, tcp, log4j, ibm-mq

I've been running JProfiler for a day or so and keep seeing new threads being created for the JMS Listener to a topic in WMQ. It seems to go through phases of dropping out every few minutes for half hour and then works fine for hours. I'm struggling to track down the reason why, there seems to be nothing in the logs on the server hosting WMQ so my next step it to turn on the logging client side in java but can't figure out how to do this. I was hoping it would be as straightforward as adding a line in the log4j file setting `log4j.logger.com.ibm=TRACE` but that didn't work. Does anyone have any ideas of how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Infocenter has some documentation as to all the classes that can be enabled and their include/exclude options.

For example, the class you want to set on the client side is `com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.trace.level` and it takes integer values.  There is no JMS tracing on the QMgr itself but there is extensive QMgr trace available using the `strmqtrc` command.

The V7 client has a lot more trace functionality and it is recommended to use it instead of the V6 client.  It is permissible to use the V7 client with the V6 QMgr.  Of course in that case the API functionality is limited to what the V6 QMgr provides.  However, the V7 client-side functionality (such as trace) is not limited by the QMgr version.

[V7 Infocenter JMS Trace](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r0/topic/com.ibm.mq.csqzaw.doc/jm10770_.htm)
[V6 Infocenter JMS Trace](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv6/v6r0/topic/com.ibm.mq.csqzaw.doc/uj10770_.htm)
[V7 WMQ Client](http://bit.ly/SupportPacMQC7)

Comment: Can you tell me where to set com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.trace.level in jboss? just put it into system-properties ?

Comment: Click the link above for v7 JMS Trace and look for the the link "The WebSphere MQ classes for JMS configuration file."  That page describes but the configuration file and the system variables that can be used. Note that those versions are all out of service and IBM repackaged everything. So if you have a later version of MQ you should check the Knowledge Center for that version. Failing that, post a new question specifying the version and whether you use the JMS classes or the Resource Adapter.

Comment: Thanks T.Rob. I solved it by changing the file ra.xml which is in wmq.jmsra.rar yesterday. Of cause,   the solution in  "The WebSphere MQ classes for JMS configuration file."   is better.